# Recommended location for Domain Model classes

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I am learning Angular 2 and I am using angular-cli to generate components and services. I am using the directory structure proposed by angular-cli (see screenshot below). I need to add some domain model object (e.g. User, Profile, etc.), but I don't know where to put them.

What is the recommended location for those objects in the directory structure?

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to have your app-wide models stored at the root level (default: `src/app`) except that those values should be in the `shared` directory (`src/app/shared`).

If you generate those models with the CLI (from the project root directory) you will run:

```
ng generate class shared/profile model
```

which will yield:

```
src/app/shared/profile.model.ts
src/app/shared/profile.model.spec.ts
```

and also add a reference to the `profile` exports to the `index.ts` within the shared directory, so you can reference them (from the root component)

```
import { Profile } from './shared';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the domain model classes are used by all the components, it can be put in a model.ts file within shared folder.